# JavaFX JDK 8 Components Not Displaying Properly

Tags: java, javafx, java-7, java-8, javafx-8

I wanted to use the control fx api for my application for predefined validation and other components like auto complete boxes etc. 
So i switched the project to jdk8 from jdk7.

Problem is the display is really unclear and weird when i switch to jdk8. This is the jdk8 view :

[image]

This is the jdk7 view :

[image]

Any suggestions? what could be the problem? ?

Comment: There are different versions of controls fx for each version of the JDK. Are you sure you are using the correct version?

Comment: even the first release of control fx gives the  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 error if compiled with jdk 7

Comment: You are correct. It looks like controls fx only supports JDK 8 and JDK 8 update 20. I'm sorry but I don't know why your UI is changing like it is when switching to JDK 8.

Comment: its very irritating.. earlier a black screen used to flicker and i stopped using jdk8 but then i needed validation and other tools like auto completion.. so i thought of using control fx

Comment: any ideas about the issue?